# Google protobuf SerializeToString function in c++ and WriteTo function in c#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, protocol-buffers, protobuf-csharp-port

I want to use google protobuf in both c# and c++.I used protobuf-csharp-port to generate the code in c#.The protobuf code in c++ and c# were generated from a same .proto file and I set the same object with the same value.

c++ code:

```
GetTokenReq getTokenReq;
getTokenReq.set_account_name("");
getTokenReq.set_login_type(8);
getTokenReq.set_auth_data("");
getTokenReq.set_is_tourist(1);
getTokenReq.set_password(g_strPwd);
```

c# code:

```
GetTokenReq.Builder reqBuilder = new GetTokenReq.Builder();
reqBuilder.SetAccountName(ByteString.CopyFrom("", Encoding.ASCII));
reqBuilder.SetLoginType(8);
reqBuilder.SetAuthData(ByteString.CopyFrom("", Encoding.ASCII));
reqBuilder.SetIsTourist(1);
reqBuilder.SetPassword(ByteString.CopyFrom(g_strPwd, Encoding.ASCII));
GetTokenReq getTokenReq = reqBuilder.Build();
```

I want to serialize the object to string so I used SerializeToString function in c++ and WriteTo function in c#.Like this:

c++ code:

```
getTokenReq.SerializeToString(&strBody);
```

c# code:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
oReq.WriteTo(stream);
byte[] buffer = stream.ToArray();
string strBody = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
```

However,the result of strBody in c++ is not as same as in c#.Why and How can I do.
[c++ value:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MinaS.png)

[c# value:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urKgZ.png)